# How to alter MQ headers using Spring JmsTemplate

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq

I'm using simple Spring JmsTemplate to send messages onto a MQ.

```
<beans:bean id="myJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <beans:property name="connectionFactory">
        <beans:ref bean="cachedConnectionFactory" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="pubSubDomain">
        <beans:value>false</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="receiveTimeout">
        <beans:value>1000</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

    <int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="sendMessageToAvengers" channel="antEventChannel" jms-template="myJMSTemplate" destination-name='com.marvel.avengers.antMan'/>
```

This works fine, however, My client application isn't able to process the message as the message format is in 'MQHRF2' by default.
How can I alter my MQ headers so as to send explicitly MQSTR format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You must set the property targetcllient=1 to send the msg as MQSTR.
To do this in sending part of java code, change the queue name as below

```
String senderQ = "queue:///MYQUEUENAME?targetClient=1";
jmsTemplate.send(senderQ, new MessageCreator() {
    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
         TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);
         message.setJMSReplyTo(replyToQ);
         return message;
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can try setting this in jmstemplate bean

```
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <!-- set format to MQSTR with "targetClient=1" parameter -->
    <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="queue:///default?targetClient=1" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="mqConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

The IBM MQ JMS interface has a property called `TARGCLIENT` which when set to the value `MQ` will not add the MQRFH2 header. I don't know whether the Spring interface allows it to be used.

Alternatively, the queue definition on the queue manager can be configured to remove the header for those applications that can't process it. This is a better way to remove the MQRFH2 header as it removes it at get time instead of at put time, thus meaning that if an application **is** able to process the MQRFH2 header, it is still there, but for those applications that cannot process it, it is removed for them.

To make the queue operate in this way, issue the following MQSC command on your queue manager:

```
ALTER QLOCAL(q-name) PROPCTL(NONE)
```

**Additional Reading**

- [Properties of IBM MQ classes for JMS objects > TARGCLIENT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q112610_.htm)
- [PROPCTL queue options](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q008230_.htm)
- [DEFINE queues - see PROPCTL attribute](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q085690_.htm)

Comment: I was able to achieve this without using spring interface, however, wanted to know if there is a way I could do this using Spring jmsTemplate. :)

I used this And I was able to put messages in MQSTR format. Using the ibm.mq.jms api.     


((com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue) queue).setTargetClient(JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);